# How does infinite scrolling like facebook in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I send ajax request to server with params[:page],
but I noticed that ajax call will return with same data.

```
def index
  @meetings = Meetings.order(:created_at).page(params[:page])
end
```

it will return next page with same data when other users create more meetings.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this approach you can avoid showing the same data,

You can send last record created_at when request for next page, no need for page_no param, and then just return next records which have created_at less than passed created_at

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gem to ease this for you, try [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem